# In GNOME-Wayland shell, How I map an touchscreen USB input to a specific video display output?

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, wayland, touch-screen

I use Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME-Wayland is default (It also happened on Ubuntu 20.x with GNOME-Wayland shell). Two touchscreens connect to system.  I face a problem:

Two USB (touchscreen) touch inputs are always mapping to one touch monitor.

From X11, I can use "xinput map-to-output {device_id} {display_name}", and it works well.)
to map the touch USB input to a specific video display output, and it works well.
But xinput under Wayland cannot not detected for an touch USB devices, so cannot obtain an device ID to use in xinput command.

Anyone know how to map touch USB input to video output?
Please help.

Thank you so much.